# Setting StockEvents with AmCharts on Minutes and Seconds

Tags: jquery, amcharts

I have had a lot of success with AmCharts for a variety of different projects. It's rather easy, I but I have added stockEvents to charts with relatively ease. However that was with date as the unique value. Now I'm using minutes and seconds and I can't seem to insert stockEvent correctly. Here is a jsfiddle of what I'm trying to do: https://jsfiddle.net/punksgt/vshkv4xq/

The believe that the issue is some where in the `stockEvents`:

```
"stockEvents": [{
"date": new Date(2012, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 592),
"type": "sign",
"backgroundColor": "#85CDE6",
"graph": "g1",
"text": "S",
"description": "This is description of an event"
}],
```

I'm ultimately looking for something like this that calls out events on the chart. https://www.amcharts.com/demos/stock-events/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`stockEvents`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/DataSet#stockEvents) needs to be set inside the associated `dataSet`. Your fiddle is setting it outside of it.

```
  "dataSets": [{
    "color": "#b0de09",
    "fieldMappings": [{
      "fromField": "value",
      "toField": "value"
    }, {
      "fromField": "volume",
      "toField": "volume"
    }],

    "dataProvider": chartData,
    "categoryField": "date",
    "stockEvents": [{
      "date": new Date(2012, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 592),
      "type": "sign",
      "backgroundColor": "#85CDE6",
      "graph": "g1",
      "text": "S",
      "description": "This is description of an event"
    }],
  }],
```

The event also needs to fall inside the date range of your data (your fiddle sets the date 1000 days before 2012-01-01, so it won't show up).

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vshkv4xq/1/)